# How to calculate principal curvature directions in 3D mesh?

Tags: npr

In non-photorealistic rendering, line direction matters much of effects. In order to achieve a good effect, I wanna rotate texture to principal curvature directions.

I have 3D mesh model(consist of triangle set). I wanna estimate principle curvature directions for each vertices in the model. You can answer this question or tell me where can I find the methods(such as give out a paper).

Comment: Could you explain the effect you're trying to create?  There might be a simpler way than doing complex geometry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We finished our work a long time ago. We wanted to realize pencil rendering effect and we used a trick to skip this principle curvature direction step.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is determining the curvature tensor. See the resources at http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Pierre.Alliez/demos/curvature/